# Looping through A Folder and all its subdirectories

Tags: loops, for-loop, import, directory

Ok.  Many trouble shooting hours ...and many error "dings" later, I'm still having the same problem.  Due to my beginner skills I'm having problems achieving the following segment of my project:

I will be as detailed as possible so I can hopefully nail it this time:

- On my computer i have a folder C:\data which contains many different subfolders.
- The subfolders are named by dates in a MMDDYY fashion. For example "040312"
- In each subfolder are excel files named after Baseball teams.  each subfolder may contain a different combination of xls files.

I am trying to write code that achieves the following objectives:

1.) Loops through all the subfolders of the C:\data folder looking for xls files that have the filenames: Angles.xls, Diamondbacks.xls, etc.

2.) If the files are found in each subfolder import the spreadsheet data and generate a plot of the data titled "Score" and "Allow".

3.) If the file is not found any given subfolder skip and continue to the next file to be located.
4.)Then save the generated plot in the same folder that the spreadsheet was imported from as a .fig and a .bmp file.

I've gotten hints to use various functions like: genpath, dir,  but the code I've been fumbling through isn't able to achieve my goals.

a) the script doesn't import the excel files from all the subfolders

b) the script wont save the .fig or .bmp file in the associated subfolder

Here is the code I have been fumbling through:

%I know all of this is wrong wrong wrong.  Please help to adjust my code to %achieve the objectives outlined above!

```
addpath(genpath('c:\data'))
folder = 'c:\data';
subdirs = dir(folder);
subdirs(~[subdirs.isdir]) = [] ; 
numberOfFolders = length(subdirs);
if numberOfFolders <= 0
    uiwait(warndlg('Number of folders = 0!'))
end
wantedfiles = {'Angels' 'Diamondbacks' 'Orioles' 'Royals' 'Yankees' 'Mets' 'Giants'};


for K = 1 : numberOfFolders
  thissubdir = subdirs(K).name;
if strcmp(thissubdir, '.') || strcmp(thissubdir, '..')
      continue; 
end
  subdirpath = [folder '\' thissubdir];

for L = 1 : length(wantedfiles)  

for wantedfiles = {'Angels' 'Diamondbacks' 'Orioles' 'Royals' 'Yankees' 'Mets' 'Giants'};
folder = '';
   fileToRead1 = [wantedfiles{1} '.xls'];
   sheetName='Sheet1';
if exist(fileToRead1, 'file') == 0
  % File does not exist
  % Skip to bottom of loop and continue with the loop
    continue;
end
```

%This is to import the data and organize it
  % All of this code I had auto-generated from importing files manually

```
   [numbers, strings, raw] = xlsread(fileToRead1, sheetName);
if ~isempty(numbers)
    newData1.data =  numbers;
end

if ~isempty(strings) && ~isempty(numbers)
    [strRows, strCols] = size(strings);
    [numRows, numCols] = size(numbers);
    likelyRow = size(raw,1) - numRows;
    % Break the data up into a new structure with one field per column.
    if strCols == numCols && likelyRow > 0 && strRows >= likelyRow
        newData1.colheaders = strings(likelyRow, :);
    end
end

% Create new variables in the base workspace from those fields.
for i = 1:size(newData1.colheaders, 2)
    assignin('base', genvarname(newData1.colheaders{i}), newData1.data(:,i));
end


% Now I execute the plotting of data
subplot (2,1,1), plot(Score,Allow)


title([wantedfiles{1} 'Testing to see if it works']);
subplot (2,1,2), plot(Allow,Score)

title('Well, did it?');
```

% here I save the generated plots, but they don't save where I want them to

```
saveas(gcf,[wantedfiles{1} ' did it work.fig']);
saveas(gcf,[wantedfiles{1} ' did it work.bmp']);
end
end
end
```

%At the end of the script I still was unable to loop over the files that I wanted
     rmpath(genpath('c:\data'));

Comment: Add a tag for the language you're using.